# Hadoop Streaming though a Runnable Jar produces no output

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I'm trying to stream data through an existing java app, and as a test just created a runnable jar to print to stdout:

```
public class Myapp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

After creating a the jar I can do this:

```
> java -jar  myapp.jar a b < input.txt > myout1.txt
```

and myout1.txt gets filled with data.  When I run this in hadoop using

> hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.1.jar -file 'myapp.jar'  -numReduceTasks 0  -input "input.txt"  -output "myout.txt"   -mapper "java -jar myapp.jar"

The job succeeds, but the myout.txt/part-* files are all empty. Reading data from stdin doesn't help, and this works in Python and Perl, or using the java API with a map function.  Is there something special about streaming through a jar or printing with `System.out.println`?

Comment: I am not able to run the hadoop job using the above command. Here is what I got from the jobtracker logs: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1. Are you sure you were able to run it using the above command?

Comment: try System.out.flush() at the end of your script.